# How do I run an integrated ros service using ONLY a launch file?

Tags: ros, launch

Im writing a launch file for turtlesim and my custom node. I need to call a rosservice /turtleX/teleport_absolute 'x=1.0 y=1.0 theta=0.0' and a rosservice clear every time I run my node.

Is it possible to put this calls in a launchfile and how would you do it?

My launchfile so far:

```
<launch>
    <node name="turtlesim" pkg="turtlesim" type="turtlesim_node"/>
    <node name="turtle_lawnmower" pkg="turtle_lawnmower" type="turtle_lawnmower_node"/>
</launch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this. First you can simply write another node that's sole job is to call the service. I'm not sure if I would strictly recommend this, but it would give you more control on parameters and conditional logic surrounding *when* the service is called.

The second option is to launch the ROS service as it's own node in the launch file.

```
<launch>
    <node name="turtlesim" pkg="turtlesim" type="turtlesim_node"/>
    <node name="turtle_lawnmower" pkg="turtle_lawnmower" type="turtle_lawnmower_node"/>

    <node pkg="rosservice" type="rosservice" name="turtle_serv" args="call /turtleX/teleport_absolute x=1.0 y=1.0 theta=0.0"/>
</launch>
```

Note that since I don't know the exact definition of your service file I'm guessing on that parameter format, and you might have to adjust that yourself.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, the service file wasnt written by me, turtleX/teleport_absolute and clear are default services in ros turtlesim.